# Validating duplicates - Comparing objects from .bin file in serialization class Java

Tags: java, hashset

I'm trying to validate a Appointment entered to make sure there is no duplicates. I've been advised to use a HashSet by other posts. However I'm getting the below error which is due to comparing against serialized objects. In the program the objects are read from the .bin file and passed into a Arraylist then the submitted appointment object is compared to that.

However I get the below error and I cannot add any appointment, is there anyway around this serialization error or should I be using another method to detect duplicates against what's in the .bin file?

*Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: classes.Appointment; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 6357417907779853216, local class serialVersionUID = -1003880423618966687*

AddAppointment code section

```
               {
                    t = new Appointment(nameStr, dayStr, hourStr);
               
                    String file = "people.bin";
                    File f = new File(file);
                    if(f.exists())
                    {
                        list = InputOutput.readRecord(file);
                    }
                    
                    if (!Validation.isDuplicate(list, t))   //if test is false 
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Already Exist");
                    }
                    
                    list.add(t);

                    //pass in list of objects
                    InputOutput.saveRecord("people.bin", list);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Appointment Entered");
                }
```

Appointment class

```
public class Appointment implements Serializable
{
    private String day;
    private String hour;
    private String name;
    

    public Appointment(String day, String hour, String name) {
        this.day = day;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public String getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public void setHour(String hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.day + " " + this.hour + " " + this.name;
 
    }
    

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(null != o) {
        if(o instanceof Appointment) {
            return ((Appointment)o).getName().equals(getName()) 
        && ((Appointment)o).getDay().equals(getDay());
        }
    }
    return false;
    }


    public int hashCode() {
    return (getName()+getDay()).hashCode();
    }
     
}
```

Validation class

```
public class Validation{
    
    public static boolean isDuplicate(ArrayList<Appointment> list, Appointment t) 
    {
         
        HashSet<Appointment> unique=new HashSet<Appointment>();
        
        for (Appointment s : list)
        {
            unique.add(s);
        }

        //The Java.util.HashSet.add() method in Java HashSet is used to add a specific element into a HashSet. 
        //this method will add the element only if the specified element is not present in the HashSet else the function will return False if the element is already present in the HashSet.
        if(unique.add(t))
        {   //  // java.util.Set only unique object so if object will not bee add in Set it will return false so can consider it as Duplicate
                 
            return true;
        }
        else{ 
            System.out.println("Not unique, return false!"); 
             return false;}
            
    
    }
}
```

```
public class InputOutput 
{
    
    ;
    
    public static void setupFile()
             throws FileNotFoundException, NotSerializableException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
          
        ArrayList<Appointment> currentlist = new ArrayList<>();
        String file = "people.bin";

        File f = new File(file);
        
        if(f.exists())
        { 
            currentlist = InputOutput.readRecord(file);
        }
        
    }
    

    
    public static void saveRecord(String fileName, ArrayList<Appointment> list)
        throws FileNotFoundException, NotSerializableException, IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fileoutstream = new FileOutputStream(fileName); 
        
        ObjectOutputStream objectoutstream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileoutstream);
        
        // write the arraylist of objects to file
        objectoutstream.writeObject(list);
        objectoutstream.close();
    }
    
    public static ArrayList<Appointment> readRecord(String fileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException, NotSerializableException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        ArrayList<Appointment> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);
        
        // read the objects from the file and dump them into the arraylist
        list = (ArrayList<Appointment>)ois.readObject();
        
        ois.close();
        
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: try by adding this statement private static final long serialVersionUID = 6529685098267757690L; in the Appointment class at class level.

Comment: @ArunSai already tried this, still no luck

Comment: @ArunSai yes this works now. I had to delete the existing .bin file and recreate a new one